# AVPlayerViewController Error: Cannot read property 'renderVideo' of null?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, swift, react-native

I'm working on a React Native application that includes video playback using AVPlayerViewController. I have a custom Swift module called `AudioVideoPlayer` that handles rendering videos. The `renderVideo` method in this module takes a URL string as input and is responsible for displaying the video using AVPlayerViewController.

However, when I call the `AudioVideoPlayer.renderVideo` method from my JavaScript code, I encounter an error: "Error playing video: [TypeError: Cannot read property 'renderVideo' of null]".

I have checked the Swift code for the `AudioVideoPlayer` module, and there is no reference to this specific error message. I suspect that the issue might be occurring somewhere else in the code or in the React Native setup.

Here's a simplified version of the Swift module:

```swift
import Foundation
import AVKit
import AVFoundation

@objc(AudioVideoPlayer)
class AudioVideoPlayer :NSObject {
  static func moduleName() -> String! {
    return "VideoPlayerBridge"
  }
  
    @objc(renderVideoFromUrl:)
    public func renderVideoFromUrl(_ urlString: String) -> String {
}
```

In my React Native code, I import the module as follows:

```js
import { NativeModules } from 'react-native';
const { AudioVideoPlayer } = NativeModules;
```

And then call the `renderVideo` method like this:

```js
const videoURL = "https://example.com/sample_video.mp4";
AudioVideoPlayer.renderVideo(videoURL);
```

I've verified that the `videoURL` is a valid string and not `null`.

Could someone please help me understand why I'm getting this error? Is there anything specific I should check in my React Native code or project setup to resolve this issue?

Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create .h file first, like this:

```
#import "RCTCalendarModule.h"

@implementation RCTCalendarModule

// To export a module named RCTCalendarModule
RCT_EXPORT_MODULE(your module name);

//code to fix 
RCT_EXTERN_METHOD(renderVideoFromUrl: (NSString *) urlString)

@end
```

And define your implement in Swift file, see more example here: [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DREQwNb99l0)